# Possible bug of `np.mgrid`?

Tags: python, numpy, debugging

In the following snippet, `128.99` is included in the output, which by definition should not. Is it a bug? Tested with both python2 and python3.

```
In [38]: np.mgrid[119.99:128.99, 0:2] 
Out[38]: 
array([[[ 119.99,  119.99],
    [ 120.99,  120.99],
    [ 121.99,  121.99],
    [ 122.99,  122.99],
    [ 123.99,  123.99],
    [ 124.99,  124.99],
    [ 125.99,  125.99],
    [ 126.99,  126.99],
    [ 127.99,  127.99],
    [ 128.99,  128.99]],

   [[   0.  ,    1.  ],
    [   0.  ,    1.  ],
    [   0.  ,    1.  ],
    [   0.  ,    1.  ],
    [   0.  ,    1.  ],
    [   0.  ,    1.  ],
    [   0.  ,    1.  ],
    [   0.  ,    1.  ],
    [   0.  ,    1.  ],
    [   0.  ,    1.  ]]])
```

Comment: It's floating point. Rounding errors are normal. You should be using `linspace` or the complex-step form of `mgrid` if you want a floating-point range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.mgrid` invoked with two arguments will fill the corresponding range with items from start to stop.

To determine the number of steps, the formula used is (see the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/bfe43b26969231cfe8196868280c07f0c0aa8f50/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py#L178)):

```
math.ceil((key[k].stop - start)/(step*1.0))
```

where the step is `1` by default. In your situation, `stop-start` is 9.000000000000014 so that the rounding by the `ceil` function generates 10 steps, of step 1: 119.99+9 = 128.99

So, no bug here.

If you rely on the number of items in mgrid, use a complex step index:

```
np.mgrid[119.99:127.99:9j, 0:2].
```

beware that now the "stop" point is inclusive, per the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html)

Comment: In summary, the problem is caused by 1) rounding error of `float` representation 2) integer number of steps is produced by `ceil` function. Therefore a very SMALL rounding error can result in DIFFERENT number of steps. PS: `decimal.Decimal()` can be used to check the exact value of a `float`